# How to manage a HSQLDB in JBoss AS7.1.x

Tags: entity, jboss7.x, hsqldb, ejb-3.1

It's my first try to use EJB3.1 entities with a JBoss AS7.1.1 server. I figured out that the HSQLDB is no longer included in the version 7 of JBoss. First I added the hsqldb.jar through the Administration Console --> Deployments --> Manage Deployments. After that I added a new Data Source through Profil --> Connector -> Datasources

My first example code works fine:

```
[...]     
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ic.lookup("java:/DefaultDS");
con = ds.getConnection();
stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.execute("drop table timers;");
stmt.execute("Create table timers(id char(10));");
stmt.execute("INSERT INTO timers  (id) VALUES (20)");
stmt.execute("INSERT INTO timers  (id) VALUES (21)");
ResultSet number = stmt.executeQuery("select * from timers");
[...]
```

My question is how I can manage (=create, drop and update new tables) the DB which is created in the folder jobss\standalone\data\hypersonic. At the moment I have no "overview" which tables are created, the structure of them and the data.

Does someone have a tip or a tutorial for me which deal with the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it was easier as I thought at the beginning. I needed to manage the DB which is stored in the AS 7.1.x Server. Because of the missing JMX-Console I wasn't able to get access to that DB over the administration. I've added the Datasource and the Manage Deployments as described in the first post.

To manage such a DB you can use the 'HSQLDB Database Manager', select 'HSQL Database Engine Standalone' as the type and 'jdbc:hsqldb:file:«MY_PATH_TO_DB_FOLDER_IN_JBOSS»' for the URL. Now I can manage the DB outside the server and EJB environment.

Thanks you fredt for your help and your inspirations.

Comment: You are welcome. Readers note: this method of access is valid only when the JEE server is not connected to the database and has shutdown the database, or the JEE server itself has shutdown.

Comment: @fredt Thank you for the update. Forgot that fact at my first post. You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

You always query INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables to find out which tables already exist. Once you know a table exists, you can execute a query that you know does not take a long time, in order to find out about the state of the data.

For example, the first query will show you if there is a 'TIMERS' table, and the second query will show if there is any data in the table:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TIMERS'
SELECT * FROM TIMERS LIMIT 1
```

Try always to define a primary key on each table in order to speed up queries.

To access a database embedded in an app server, you should add the org.hsqldb.server.Servlet class as a servlet then connect to the app server using a database management tool and a URL such as `jdbc:hsqldb:http:<your servlet url here>`

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I've heard and read of the timers-table before. My DB seems to be completely new and empty. But thats not my problem. Your example may work for a ejb well but what I am looking for is more a management console or better a way to gain access to the structure of the database. I am new to JBoss AS 7.1 but I've seen some examples for older versions (JBoss 4,5) where you can manage the DB over a web interface of the server. With a double click on the jar I have a view to manage the DB, can create content but the data will note be stored. Hope you can understand me.

Comment: Added option to access the DB from outside.

Comment: Do you have a complete example or a link to a tutorial elsewhere? An alternative to the old "jmx-console" doesnt exist, right?